# How to draw a funnel plot for an observational meta-analysis which concerns only with prevalence rates (no odds ratios or standard errors etc.)?

Tags: effect-size, funnel-plot

I need to draw a funnel plot for my meta-analysis, which is observational and aggregates prevalence rates of a certain medical condition. As far as I know, a funnel plot is a scatter plot of effect size measures against sample sizes. Therefore I have some difficulties in my study which I think does not have an effect size measure:

1. I don't know if there is any effect size measures for prevalence of a single study? Each study reports a single prevalence, so I have a bunch of ratios (0-100%) only. Each study has only one single ratio, so there can be no "prevalence ratios" or "prevalence odds ratios".
2. Can I plot the ratios (the prevalences) against sample sizes, instead of non-existent effect sizes against sample sizes?
3. Can I calculate 95% CI for each ratio (each prevalence), and use it as the effect size? If so, does it help when the Y axis is already "Sample Size" and CI is directly affected by sample size?
4. Do you have any other hints, in addition to the nice ones given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7476/alternative-funnel-plot-without-using-standard-error-se)?

Many thanks.

Comment: The prevalence ratio **is** the effect measure in a prevalence study. Another possibile effect measure would be the *prevalence odds ratio*. [This paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1247374/pdf/ehp0112-001047.pdf) discusses the two measures. I've found a funnel plots with prevalences [here](http://www.who.int/bulletin/volumes/90/2/11-091850/en/) (Fig. 3) and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1438463913000448#). As the prevalence is a proportion, it might be possible to calculate the standard error if the sample size is given.

Comment: Many thanks dear Serdash. It was such a relief to see those figures and hearing that prevalence itself is the effect size measure. About the POR, I had read that article (very hastily though) but thought POR  is calculable only when we have two prevalence rations at hand, right? (this is why I said each study reports a single prevalence).

Comment: Jup, for the POR, you need the prevalence rate of the cases and controls.

Comment: Ah hold on a sec please, do you mean the ratio of prevalence 1 / prevalence 2, by the term "prevalence ratio"? Or did you mean "prevalence" by "prevalence ratio"? In my case, each study has only a single prevalence (which is itself a ratio of affected people divided by the sample size). It does not have any P1/P2 ratios. Do you think can I still use such prevalence rates as effect sizes?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Of course those figures show I can apparently. I was curious because I didn't see "prevalence" itself among effect size measures here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59173/21054) can shed further light unto the issue.

Comment: Update: I think I can calculate SE for prevalences too, thus SE is not non-existent. :)