# What kind of cut-offs are used for publication bias tests in meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, publication-bias

I have performed meta-analysis and included four different tests for publication bias in the analysis - classic fail-safe N, Orwin's fail-safe N, Duval and Tweedie's trim and fill as well as funnel plots. The tests did not seem to indicate publication bias in my material - according to classic fail-safe N 23 papers would be needed to bring the result to p > 0.05, according to Orwin's fail-safe N 8 papers would be needed to reduce the OR into a trivial one, trim and fill test did not show adjustments and funnel plot was symmetrical.

However, one of my reviewers wants me to include cut-offs for publication bias tests in the Methods. I have tried to look for any cut-offs that would be commonly used with these tests but in many cases even the interpretation of results is not very exact. How should I proceed with this problem, what should I answer to the reviewer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of any fail-safe N method is depreciated. Please see [Becker (2005)](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vd4VpxiJp5QC&lpg=PA122&ots=WJRp5vhXgZ&dq=orwin's%20fail%20safe%20n&hl=de&pg=PA122#v=onepage&q=orwin's%20fail%20safe%20n&f=false) and check out the *Conclusions* section. Here, she states:

> "Given the other approaches that now exist for dealing with publication bias, the fail-safe N should be abandoned in favour of other, more informative analyses [...]".

You also might want to read her statement in *Summary of the Examples*:

> "The incredible range of values shown here reveals one of the greatest weaknesses of the failsafe N computations - it is difficult to interpret the values without a statistical criterion."

The "trim and fill method" is a good starting point. However, you also might want to give Egger's regression method a try which, for instance, is described in Sterne/Egger (2005) (please note that Egger et al. (1997) suggest a weighted least squares regression, while Sterne and Egger (2005: 101) recommend a simple OLS regression). See also this CV question on [Egger’s linear regression method intercept in meta analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/eggers-linear-regression-method-intercept-in-meta-analysis).

For a general overview of methods to detect publication bias see Sutton et al. (2000) or these slides by [Birgit Schrödle](http://www.biostat.uzh.ch/teaching/phd/doktorandenseminar/schroedle.pdf).

**References**

Egger, M., G. Davey Smith, M. Schneider, C. Minder (1997), Bias in meta-analysis detected by a simple, graphical test British Medical Journal 315: 629-634.

Sterne, J.A.C., M. Egger (2005), Regression Methods to Detect Publication and Other Bias in
Meta-Analysis. Pp. 99-110 in: H.R. Rothstein, A.J. Sutton, M. Borenstein (eds.), Publication Bias in Meta-Analysis. Prevention, Assessment and Adjustments, The Atrium, Southern Gate, Chichester: Wiley.

Sutton, A.J., F. Song, S.M. Gilbody, K.R. Abrams (2000), Modelling publication bias in meta-analysis: a review. Statistical Methods in Medical Research 9: 421-445

Comment: Thank you for the prompt and very useful comment! I will proceed with the Egger's regression method.